# Why was Rico listed amongst the dead?

Tags: starship-troopers

In *Starship Troopers*, when Carmen was scanning through the list of fallen soldiers Rico was clearly designated as **deceased**.

[image: Rico KIA]

He was specifically listed as killed-in-action rather than missing-in-action. Yet Rico was still alive. We later see him being treated in a medical facility. [According to this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/109128/how-did-rico-survive-the-initial-assault-in-starship-troopers), he was saved from the battle by Lieutenant Rasczak. However, that doesn't explain how he came to be listed as dead. Somebody somewhere must have made the decision to list him as KIA.

**How did this come to be?**

Book or movie answers are fine.

Comment: Perhaps the "fog of war"? Keeping accurate records was notoriously difficult in past World Wars - and this war took place on a much larger geographic scale (between different planets). I don't have a canon answer however, just a possibility.

Comment: Regarding your final line, this event didn't happen in the book.

Comment: @HarryJohnston Why would "Book or movie answers are fine" be in the book? ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the film Johnny was seen (on the live camera feed at the start of the film) horribly wounded behind enemy lines. His own comrades would have reported him missing from their evac pod, likely killed and the official record would reflect that. The bugs don't, as far as they're aware, take prisoners.

[image]

---

Interestingly, in the [original script](http://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Starship-Troopers.html) the course of events are slightly different. Dizzy loses Johnny behind enemy lines and he's rescued by his former high school teacher, now a Lieutenant, Jean Rasczak. Because he was evacced by a different brigade, his survival wouldn't have been noted (yet).

> **JOHNNY:** *AAAAAAAAAAAAA!*
>
> Crushing jaws close around him, crushing, cutting his flesh. Johnny
> brings the muzzle of the pulse gun under the hopper's nerve stem and
> SPLAT! blows its head apart.
>
> **DIZZY:** *Johnny! JOHNNY! WHERE ARE YOU? JOHNNY! Johnny...!*
>
> But Dizzy can't find Johnny, and soon she's lost in the smoke. Johnny
> looks down at the terrible hole in his leg where bright arterial blood
> gushes.
>
> ...
>
> **VOICE (O.S.):** *Take my hand !*
>
> Johnny reaches out. A STEEL HAND takes his, dragging him back as bugs
> attack. His rescuers's pulse cannon thunders overhead. Bug parts fly
> as  insects swarm in for the kill.

Comment: Noone was around when he got stabbed in the leg, though. Just a load of people running away in retreat.

Comment: @TheDarkLord - He was live on Network television.

Comment: Ah, true. I forgot about the abandoned camera on the floor. But then surely the camera would've also filmed his rescue/survival?

Comment: @TheDarkLord - It cut to static. Presumably a bug stood on it